# Datatables Responsiveness - Searchbar (bootstrap)

Tags: datatables

I have started to implement Datatables in a project.
 My Project is based on Bootstrap 3.
 I have build up a package with the necessary files on the datatables download-page and created a simple datatable based on the docs. Everything works fine, but I have a problem with responsiveness. Have a look at the following screenshot:

[image: Datatables Problem]

As you see. the search-bar has problems.

The table has the following HTML:

`<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive table-condensed table-hover" id="event_history" cellspacing="0">` .......

The table has the following JS:

```
var table = $('#event_history').DataTable({
 responsive: true,
 colReorder: true,
 lengthChange: true,
 "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
 });
```

Perhaps somebody can help me to solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controls in DataTables with Bootstrap styling wrap nicely when table occupies full page width, see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/dxk6o3xm/).

However I think you're showing your table in a panel that doesn't occupy full page width, which prevents `col-` rules from being applied, as shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5w8p5aut/2/). You can use special crafted value for [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option to configure column layout for one specific table based on your expected container sizes.

For example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   responsive: true,
   dom: 
      "<'row text-center'<'col-xs-12'l><'col-xs-12'f>>" +
      "<'row'<'col-xs-12'tr>>" +
      "<'row text-center'<'col-xs-12'i><'col-xs-12'p>>"
});
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/5w8p5aut/3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Hi, all of your mentioned points are correct and your example Looks like my table. I implemented the code and it works. ... but it doesn't look good :-( It would be great to have the "search-bar" on the right and the "length" on the left on normal Screen. On break-Point for smaller screen they should be like on your last example and booth be centered. But I think it is too complicated ...